# An issue with deploying grails war file

Tags: grails

Using grails 2.0.2 I created a war file for my application and placed in the web apps directory of a jetty instance. I get this error. The application works fine in local testing with grails run-app. What am I doing wrong?

```
2012-03-01 18:12:14.151:WARN::Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext{/pokermetrics,[file:/tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-pokermetrics.war-_pokermetrics-any-/webinf/, jar:file:/home/j2play/j2play/jetty-hightide-7.2.2.v20101205/webapps/pokermetrics.war!/]},/home/j2play/j2play/jetty-hightide-7.2.2.v20101205/webapps/pokermetrics.war
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'hibernateProperties' while setting bean property 'hibernateProperties'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'hibernateProperties': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dialectDetector' while setting bean property 'properties' with key [hibernate.dialect]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dialectDetector': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jdbc.support.MetaDataAccessException: Error while extracting DatabaseMetaData; nested exception is org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Unsupported connection setting "SHUTDOWN" [90113-147])
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(ReloadAwareAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:449)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.getApplicationContext(DefaultRuntimeSpringConfiguration.java:153)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:170)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:641)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1181)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:36)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:481)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:137)
"2012_03_01.stderrout.log" 709L, 79353
```

Data source.groovy:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "org.h2.Driver"
    username = "XXXX"
    password = "XXXX"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = true
    cache.provider_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheProvider'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop','update'
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb"
        }
    }
    test {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb"
        }
    }
    production {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "update"
            url = "jdbc:h2:file:prodDb;shutdown=true"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your `DataSource.groovy` look like? The cause of that error seems to be `Unsupported connection setting "SHUTDOWN" [90113-147]` (at the very end of the message).

Comment: I removed the shutdown=true from the prodDB line and everything seems to be fine but I have seen that parameter set in all the examples. Not sure why I had to remove it.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's in there by default. Not sure why it wouldn't work with your particular instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like an older pre-2.0 application that was using HSQLDB and was upgraded to H2. HSQLDB and H2 configurations are fairly similar, but not all JDBC url parameters are supported in both. Here's the `production` block that you'd get in a new 2.0.x application:

```
production {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "update"
        url = "jdbc:h2:prodDb;MVCC=TRUE"
        properties {
           maxActive = -1
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis=1800000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis=1800000
           numTestsPerEvictionRun=3
           testOnBorrow=true
           testWhileIdle=true
           testOnReturn=true
           validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        }
    }
}
```

But you'll probably want to switch to a more robust database at some point, e.g. MySQL/PostgreSQL/Oracle/etc.